# EFCore: Entities association error during a simple property update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I'd like to set one bool property in my controller and save it to the database. EF throws an error about other properties that are not even modified.

> The association between entities 'User' and 'RequestDetail' with the
>   key value 'System.InvalidOperationException: The association between
>   entities 'User' and 'RequestDetail' with the key value '{Id: 40}' has
>   been severed but the relationship is either marked as 'Required' or is
>   implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable. If the
>   dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship
>   is severed, then setup the relationship to use cascade deletes.

If I call my method with an additional parameter it has to change one RequestDetail record's RequestSent property and that is working great.
But calling the method without this additional parameter it has to change this property on more than one RequestDetail records. And this is where it throws the error. I don't modify anything associated with User.
If it has to do more records at once it throws this error. Even if I rewrite the foreach into a while with FirstOrDefaults() and immediate SaveChanges() it throws error on the second round.

My method:

```
var head = await _ctx.RequestHeads.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.Id == d.Id);
if (!d.DetailId.HasValue) {
            var details = _ctx.RequestDetails.Include(x=>x.BuyerUser)
                            .Where(x=>x.RequestHeadId == head.Id); 
//not working, always throws an error if it has to modify more than one record
            await details.ForEachAsync(detail => {
                detail.RequestSent = true;
            });
        } else {
            var detail = head.Details.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == d.DetailId.Value); //works ok, always
            detail.RequestSent = true;
        }
        await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
```

My models:

```
public class RequestHead
{
    [Key, MaxLength(15)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public int CreateUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreateUserId")]
    public User CreateUser { get; set; }

    public DateTime? AcceptDate { get; set; }
    public int? AcceptUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AcceptUserId")]
    public User AcceptUser { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CloseDate { get; set; }
    public int? CloseUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CloseUserId")]
    public User CloseUser { get; set; }     
    public int? CloseReason { get; set; }   
    public bool IsArchive { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(8)]
    public string OrganizationCode { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrganizationCode")]
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RequestDetail> Details { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RequestAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}

public class RequestDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string RequestHeadId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RequestHeadId")]
    public RequestHead RequestHead { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductCode")]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public bool NoProductCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public int CreateUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreateUserId")]
    public User CreateUser { get; set; }


    public DateTime? DelegateDate { get; set; }
    public int? DelegateUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DelegateUserId")]
    public User DelegateUser { get; set; }


    public int? BuyerUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BuyerUserId")]
    public User BuyerUser { get; set; }

    public bool RequestSent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RequestAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }

}
```

Context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RequestHead>()
            .HasOne(r=>r.CreateUser)
            .WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
modelBuilder.Entity<RequestHead>()
            .HasMany(r => r.Details)
            .WithOne(x=>x.RequestHead)
            .HasForeignKey(rd => rd.RequestHeadId);
modelBuilder.Entity<RequestDetail>()
            .HasOne(r=>r.CreateUser)
            .WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Comment: Not sure if related, but the two `.WithOne()` in `User` relationships look very suspicious. They probably should be `.WithMany()`. Another difference is that the "non working" query contains `.Include(x=>x.BuyerUser)`.

Comment: @IvanStoev Include(x=>x.BuyerUser) was just a test if the problem could be that navigation properties are not loaded. Good point on the .WithOne() however, I'm sure this must be something at my context configuration. Thanks!

Comment: @IvanStoev You solved it, WithOne() caused the problem. I'm not truly understand however, why was it thrown only when modifying more records at once and what was behind the error message?

Comment: Well, most of the EF messages are...confusing :) I can live with that (they have a lot of functional thigs to do, so I guess the messages are the lowest priority). What about the behavior, I guess with one-to-one the code expects single record, so when the second record with the same FK comes in, they get confused and decided that the record is deleted :) Just a guess - the actual code is quite complicated.

Comment: @IvanStoev Would you mind posting this as an answer so I could close this issue?

Comment: Have no time to compose a good answer. Please feel free to post a self answer. Glad it helped, happy coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to change RequestDetail<=>User relations from WithOne() to WithMany(). Although the error message is somewhat misleading, a possible explanation from @IvanStoev is the following:

> I guess with one-to-one the code expects single record, so when the
>   second record with the same FK comes in, they get confused and decided
>   that the record is deleted